# Mysql How do I insert multiple table with duplicate key checking?

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates, primary-key, unique-key

I hope to this work.
When UserAccount table duplicated, Out Parameter put -1.
When UserInfo table duplicated, Out Parameter put -2.
When all work is succeed, Out Parameter put LAST_INSERT_ID.

UserAccount Table

```
CREATE TABLE UserAccount (
    SocialType ENUM('Google', 'Facebook'),
    SocialID BINARY(16),
    UserID INT UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    PRIMARY KEY(SocialType, SocialID)
);
```

UserInfo Table

```
CREATE TABLE UserInfo (
    UserID INT,
    Nickname VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE, 

    PRIMARY KEY(UserID),
    FOREIGN KEY(UserID) REFERENCES UserAccount(UserID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
);
```

I want to insert tables with duplicate checking in procedure.

But it failed to work and seems inefficient.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_CreateNewUser(
    socialType ENUM('Google','Facebook'), 
    socialID VARCHAR(100), 
    nickname VARCHAR(20), 
    OUT result INT)
Work:BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UserAccount WHERE SocialType = socialType AND SocialID = UNHEX(MD5(socialID)))
    THEN
        SET result = -1;
        Leave Work;
    END IF;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UserInfo WHERE Nickname = nickname)
    THEN
        SET result = -2;
        Leave Work;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO UserAccount() VALUE(socialType, UNHEX(MD5(socialID)), 0);
    INSERT INTO UserInfo(UserID, Nickname) VALUE(LAST_INSERT_ID(), nickname);
    SET result = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

What is the best way I can do in this situation?
Thanks.

Comment: A trigger on duplicate rows?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your trigger, you don't want to have duplicate keys in your database, as you are bypassing the insert when you find one.

So all you have to do is have your unique indexes set up correctly in your first table, which will do that work for you, and produce a display in your application. 
Do the below:

```
ALTER TABLE `UserAccount` ADD UNIQUE `UserAccount`(`socialType`, `socialID`);
```

Since your data appears to be 1 to 1, id put all of this in the same table, and then you wouldn't need the trigger.